# IF condition not working under @auth in blade template

Tags: php, laravel

In my project, user can register himself either with Facebook or through Registration form.

I have a button on blade template. I'm putting restriction on it. If the guest user clicks on the button, a modal appears saying "Please Login or Register". But if the registered user clicks on the button, here I wanted to put following two checks with if condition:

1. If the email is not verified and Facebook_id is null then redirect to verify.email blade.
2. If the  email is not verified but Facebook_id is not null then redirect to promotion blade

Now the guest user can click on button and it gives a popup for login/register but once the user is done with login/register then rest of code doesn't work and it doesn't show the button for registered users.

After completing the Login/Registration step, when the user gets back to the blade , there is no any button, don't know why. Seems like the code under @auth not working.

Blade

```
    @guest
         <!-- Button trigger modal -->
             <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">
                        {{ __('Continue')}}
              </button>
         <!-- Modal -->
                        
        <div id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
                            
       <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
         <div class="modal-content">
           <div class="modal-header">
             <h5 class="modal-title col-12 text-center" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Verification</h5>
               <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                 <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                                    </div>

                <div class="modal-body">
                  <p>This page is restricted. Please <a href="{{route('login') }}" class="tooltip-test" title="Tooltip">Login</a> or <a href="{{route('getRegister')}}" class="tooltip-test" title="Tooltip">Register</a> to generate the code.</p>
                </div>
                
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>

    @endguest

      @auth
      @if(\Auth::check() && \Auth::user()->email_verified_at == '' && \Auth::user()->provider_id == '')
        <a  href="{{route('auth.verify') }}">{{ __('Continue')}}</a>

   @elseif (\Auth::check() && \Auth::user()->email_verified_at == '' && \Auth::user()->provider_id != '')
        <a  href="{{route('dynamicDropDown-for-private-seller') }}">{{ __('Continue')}}</a>
       @endif

     @endauth
```

Comment: try add a space between @if and the starting parantheses. `@if ()`

Comment: @PatricNox Nope. Didn't work

Comment: Why are you checking `auth()->check()` twice? Once in `@auth` and again in `@if`

Comment: `@auth` directive is equals to `<?php if(auth()->guard()->check()): ?>` It might be because of using nested if without brackets`{`. `@auth` and `@if` don't use `{` in their definition.

Comment: @BABAKASHRAFI
You are right but I just wanted to double check if my auth is working and also before knowing the status of database fields, I wanted to make sure that my user is logged in.

Comment: @BABAKASHRAFI Please check my answer below.

Comment: @PatricNox Please check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself.

So I was putting 2 conditions as per question

```
1) If the email is not verified and Facebook_id is null then redirect to verify.email blade.

2) If the email is not verified but Facebook_id is not null then redirect to promotion blade
```

I forgot to think what if the user email is already verified and he lands on the page, In this case, there was no action defined for such a user so button was not showing.

I simply added third condition in my if statement so before @endif I simply added this line

```
  @elseif(\Auth::user()->email_verified_at != '' && \Auth::user()->provider_id == '')
    <a  href="{{route('dynamicDropDown-for-private-seller') }}">{{ __('Continue')}}</a>
```

Now it's working perfect!